# Can we delete a trigger in Quicksilver?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, quicksilver, alfred

I can add a trigger by clicking on + under Triggers -> All Triggers.

But, I can't find a way to delete a trigger. Is it possible to delete a trigger completely in Quicksilver? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just select the trigger you want to delete, and then press the minus symbol in the window's bottom border, next to the plus symbol.